# $n\times n$ matrix with all eigenvalues equal to $1$ or $0$. Does a conjugated matrix with only $1$'s and $0$'s exist?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix with all eigenvalues equal to $1$ or $0$.  Is there a conjugated matrix $B = XAX^{-1}$ for some $X$ such that all the *elements* equal either $1$ or $0$?

My thoughts so far:
$A$ is not necessarily positive semi-definite..

Given the assumption that $A$ has only eigenvalues that are $0$ or $1$ doesn't really imply anything obvious that we can use.  I don't see why there would be a conjugated matrix with all the elements equal either to $1$ or $0$.

So I'm currently trying to come up with a counterexample...

Edit: Actually, a counterexample might be the wrong path to take.  The question is just asking for the *existence* of such a matrix...

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Jordan normal form. Note that since every field contains $1$ and $0$, the Jordan form of ***your*** $A$ always exists, even if the underlying field is not algebraically closed.

Comment: So, put A into Jordan form, which is to say A's eigenvalues of 1's and 0's are on the diagonal of a conjugated matrix, appearing as many times on the diagonal as their algebraic multiplicity.  Then "at most" we have some stuff above the diagonal of this conjugated matrix, namely 1's above the diagonal.  After that (and also below the diagonal), this conjugated matrix contains all zeros.  A Jordan normal form of A - or any matrix - always has this form, which is a sum of a diagonal matrix and a nilpotent matrix.  Hmm...what do you think, @user1551?  Feel to comment and correct me :)  Thanks...

Comment: @LebronJames In general, the Jordan form of a matrix $A$ will have the eigenvalues of $A$ on the diagonal, some 0s and 1s on the super-diagonal and zeros everywhere else. But there's a catch: the Jordan form always exists *over the algebraic closure of the ground field*, but not necessarily over the original field. For example, if a real matrix $A$ has some non real eigenvalues, then obviously you cannot find a real matrix $X$ such that $XAX^{-1}$ (which is real, because products of real matrices are real) is equal to the Jordan form of $A$ (which contains non real entries).

Comment: You are lucky, however, because the eigenvalues of $A$ in *your* case are members of the ground field. So, there always exist some $X$, whose entries lie in the ground field, such that $XAX^{-1}$ is the Jordan form of $A$.

Comment: That was an awesome explanation - thank you so much, @user1551! Have a great night :)

Comment: @LebronJames Thanks. Merry Christmas and a happy new year.

Comment: Merry Christmas and a Happy New Year to you too, @ user1551! :)